# How do I generate trace file of an AVC bitstream in JSVM?

Tags: scalability, trace, avconv, extractor, bitstream

I have got stuck in this question for about a month.

I want to generate trace file of an AVC bitstream in JSVM.
   It always shows:
   " No scalability SEI message found!
     Extractor exit. "

Please kindly help me.

Elvin

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed correctly JSVM in your pc i will provide you directions regarding Linux environment.
First of all you have to generate the bitstream file.
To do that you have to edit properly one config file for example main.cfg
In this file you provide desired parameters of your encoding
anyway in this link you have a detailed example that will help you.

http://r2d2n3po.tistory.com/52

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding more information instead of off-site resources.